# Printing doc created in webview

Tags: microsoft-word, printing

I've been sent a document that looks fine in web view, but when switched to print view runs way off the page. When I try to set margins the body seems to be pushed more off the page. Are there any quick fixes to get the document to fit on a page so it can be printed? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sorted- there was a table with no borders holding everything in place. Reduced the size of that and it worked perfectly